# Mobile responsive menu button is not responding to jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a responsive menu button for my navigation bar, and it does not seem to be responding to a mouse click.

```js
$("span.nav-btn").click(function()
    $("ul.nav-toggle").slidetoggle();
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh86ea79/6/)

Comment: `slidetoggle` -> `slideToggle`. Also you're missing a curly brace `{`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS has a syntax error. Missing `{` at the first line and the method name `slideToggle` (with capital "T").

```
$("span.nav-btn").click(function() {  // <== HERE ===
  $("ul.nav-toggle").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problems:**

- The click function is missing an opening curly brace `{`
- jQuery is case-sensitive so `slidetoggle`, should be   `slideToggle`

**Notes**

- in your fiddle is not loading the jQuery library

---

```js
$("span.nav-btn").click(function() {
  $("ul.nav-toggle").slideToggle();
})
```

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #6a5750;
  padding-top: .01%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transitiion: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #nav {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #nav li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #6a5750;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-btn:before {
    content: "Menu"
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-scroll-header id="nav">
  <span class="nav-btn"></span>
  <ul class="nav-toggle">
    <li><a data-scroll href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#html">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#css">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#video">Video</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a data-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```